# To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am writing a custom hook I need to send update value from useEffect but isValid value is lost and sends always false did i missed something in useEffect or i am using this in incorrect way

```
 export const useBasicValidity = (numb, name, dd, month, year) => {
  let isValid = false;

 const checkIsValid = (numb, name, dd, month, year) => {
      // some validation checks 
    return boolean value;
    };
  useEffect(() => {
      isValid = checkIsValid(numb, name, dd, month, year);
      }, [numb, name, dd, month, year]);

   return isValid;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common pattern I've run in to. You want to do something, check validation in this case, when some variables change and store the result a variable.

Keep in mind use effect happens after a render per the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).

> Instead, use useEffect. The function passed to useEffect will run
> after the render is committed to the screen. Think of effects as an
> escape hatch from React’s purely functional world into the imperative
> world.

So `isValid` has already done everything you meant it to do by the time `useEffect` runs. What you need to happen is `useEffect` to run because one of your variables changed, and trigger a new render with the new value of `isValid`. So, `isValid` should be in state. Change your code to:

```
const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(false);

const checkIsValid = (numb, name, dd, month, year) => {
  // some validation checks
  return boolean;
};
useEffect(() => {
  setIsValid(checkIsValid(numb, name, dd, month, year));
}, [numb, name, dd, month, year]);
```

But, there is another way to do this! You can sometimes combine a state and an effect into `useMemo`:

```
const checkIsValid = (numb, name, dd, month, year) => {
  // some validation checks
  return boolean;
};

const isValid = useMemo(() => {
  setIsValid(checkIsValid(numb, name, dd, month, year));
}, [numb, name, dd, month, year]);
```

Per the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies), you should have `checkIsValid` either in your memo / effect if it isn't used anywhere else or listed as a dependency to that effect / memo. The second option, as a dependency, will cause it to run every render because the function is recreated every render (even though it does the same thing). So when React checks the dependencies of `useEffect` it'll see a reference to a new function for `checkIsValid` and trigger the effect. That's bad. So you'll need the function to use `useCallback`:

```
const checkIsValid = useCallback((numb, name, dd, month, year) => {
  // some validation checks
  return boolean;
}, [dependencies here]);

const isValid = useMemo(() => {
  setIsValid(checkIsValid(numb, name, dd, month, year));
}, [numb, name, dd, month, year, checkIsValid]);
```

The same idea applies if you use `useEffect`. Now that function will only be a new reference if the function actually changed (that's what you want anyways).